# What determines if I get Ka coins?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I thought at first I got Ka coins for every monster I defeated, but that doesn't seem to be the case - they seem to be rather random now.

Is there a method to this madness, or are Ka coins just a random drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method to the madness: not every monster would grant you Ka Coins since it's based on their [phylum](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Monster_Types).

As you can read on the [Ka Coin wiki page](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Ka_coin) you get these drops:

- **2 coins:** All monsters of the Dude, Hippy, Hobo or Pirate phyla;
- **1 coin:** All monsters of the Beast, Bug, Elf, Fish, Goblin, Humanoid, Mer-Kin, Orc, Penguin, or Elemental phyla

Also a level 14+ [Priest servant](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Priest) increases all Ka drops by one, but only for monsters that already drop Ka.

If you also happen to have a [Crown of Ed the Undying](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/The_Crown_of_Ed_the_Undying), you would get a chance, at the end of combat, to find a Ka coin after fighting Undead opponents if you have it equipped.